# Default compression when using HTTPS in iqxmlrpc?

Tags: c++, http, https, xml-rpc

I'm using iqxmlrpc as my xml-rpc library. I implemented a simple test (a server that provides a "sum" method and a client that calls it a hundred times) and measured the bandwidth used by both HTTP and HTTPS (using tcpdump). While HTTP used about 60KB, HTTPS used only 20KB - is there any default compression when using iqxmlrpc over HTTPS?

Note: only one connection is established, since I use the "keep-alive" HTTP option. If I don't use it, HTTP uses about 600 bytes/call, while HTTPS uses about 2KB/call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, iqxmlrpc is using a "default compression" mode when using HTTPS. According to [Mike](http://www.belshe.com/2010/11/18/ssl-compression-and-you/), this can be checked on the packet capture by looking at the "Client Hello" message from the SSL client, by looking at the "Compression methods" field. As I could verify, this is true for iqxmlrpc:

[image: iqxmlrpc packet capture: "Client Hello" message]

To be (extra) sure, I also checked the "Server Hello" message:

[image: iqxmlrpc packet capture: "Server Hello" message]

And it's true: DEFLATE method for compression :)